# Flatten rows into two columns (like even and odd), almost like a pivot, but grouping by another column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a situation where my data is in the format of the `#SourceData` table, and I need to get it into the format of the `#FinalData` table, with the example code below.

A little verbal explanation is that the `RowNumber` column of the `#SourceData` table is ordering dates, grouping by the `TrackingNumber` column. Dates with an odd number in the `RowNumber` column will go into `Date1`, and an even number going into `Date2`.

It seems like it could be a `PIVOT`, but not quite, and it's starting to make my brain melt. **Note** that one TrackingNumber (not included) has over 100 dates.

Example data:

```
CREATE Table #SourceData 
(
    TrackingNumber int NULL,
    Date1 date NULL,
    Date2 date NULL,
    RowNumber int NULL
);

INSERT INTO #SourceData
      SELECT 3   , '09/18/2016', NULL, 1
UNION SELECT 3   , '12/21/2016', NULL, 2
UNION SELECT 12  , '01/30/2018', NULL, 1
UNION SELECT 12  , '01/30/2018', NULL, 2
UNION SELECT 12  , '03/01/2019', NULL, 3
UNION SELECT 12  , '03/05/2019', NULL, 4
UNION SELECT 12  , '04/19/2020', NULL, 5
UNION SELECT 23  , '02/14/2017', NULL, 1
UNION SELECT 130 , '04/12/2017', NULL, 1
----------------------------------------

CREATE Table #FinalData 
(
    TrackingNumber int NULL,
    Date1 date NULL,
    Date2 date NULL
);

INSERT INTO #FinalData
      SELECT 3   , '09/18/2016', '12/21/2016'
UNION SELECT 12  , '01/30/2018', '01/30/2018'
UNION SELECT 12  , '03/01/2019', '03/05/2019'
UNION SELECT 12  , '04/19/2020', NULL
UNION SELECT 23  , '02/14/2017', NULL
UNION SELECT 130 , '04/12/2017', NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matches required output I believe. Note this approach requires reducing the rows via `select distinct` so it may not be as efficient as a second approach:

```
select distinct
  TrackingNumber
, case when RowNumber % 2 > 0 then Date1
       else lag(date1,1) over(partition by TrackingNumber order by RowNumber)
  end as Date1
, case when RowNumber % 2 = 0 then Date1 
       else lead(date1,1) over(partition by TrackingNumber order by RowNumber)
       end as Date2
from #SourceData
```

| TrackingNumber | Date1 | Date2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2016-09-18 | 2016-12-21 |
| 12 | 2018-01-30 | 2018-01-30 |
| 12 | 2019-03-01 | 2019-03-05 |
| 12 | 2020-04-19 | *null* |
| 23 | 2017-02-14 | *null* |
| 130 | 2017-04-12 | *null* |

An alternative approach, which may be better in performance is to use an outer apply:

```
select
    d.TrackingNumber
  , d.date1
  , oa.Date2
  , d.RowNumber
from #SourceData d
outer apply (
  select s.date1
  from #SourceData s
  where s.TrackingNumber = d.TrackingNumber
  and s.RowNumber = d.RowNumber + 1
  ) oa (Date2)
where d.RowNumber % 2 > 0
```

| TrackingNumber | date1 | Date2 | RowNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2016-09-18 | 2016-12-21 | 1 |
| 12 | 2018-01-30 | 2018-01-30 | 1 |
| 12 | 2019-03-01 | 2019-03-05 | 3 |
| 12 | 2020-04-19 | *null* | 5 |
| 23 | 2017-02-14 | *null* | 1 |
| 130 | 2017-04-12 | *null* | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ii7SMV9d)

Note the RowNumber is included in the second purely to demonstrate that this approach does process fewer rows. Also note you could also output both RowNumber(s) if the outer apply is modified like this:

```
outer apply (
  select s.date1, s.RowNumber
  from #SourceData s
  where s.TrackingNumber = d.TrackingNumber
  and s.RowNumber = d.RowNumber + 1
  ) oa (Date2, RowNumber2)
```

Comment: GASP, what is this lag() and lead() magic!?   Give me some time to research implement this tomorrow morning.

Comment: I would focus on the second approach. Lead and lag are very helpful, but here the outer apply with correlated subquery is more efficient.

Comment: I appreciate your time Adrian!!  You saved me lots of lost sleep :)